# Does the square root of $i$ necessitate quaternions?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

The square root of *i* is $\frac{\sqrt{2} + i \sqrt{2}}{2}$. But how is it valid to use a number in expressing the square root of that number?

Comment: The square root of $i$ is not **defined** as $\frac{\sqrt2+i\sqrt2}{2}$: it just **is** that number.

Comment: I have fixed this.

Comment: A square root of 1 is 1.  Surely you don't find that objectionable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of complex numbers form an algebraically closed field. Hence, there exists solutions to $z^2=i$. You may want to look up the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). This guarantees that there are no rabbit holes, i.e., you do not need to move away from complex numbers. The problem of solving for square-roots, cube-roots and in general any polynomial equation is solved once and for all by the complex numbers.

In your case, you want to find a $z$ such that $z^2 = i$. If $z=x+iy$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we get that
$$z^2 = (x^2-y^2) + i(2xy) = i \implies x = \pm y \text{ and } xy = \dfrac12 \implies x=y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}} \text{ or } x=y= - \dfrac1{\sqrt2}$$
Hence, we get that
$$i^{1/2} = \pm \left(\dfrac{\sqrt2 + i \sqrt2}{2}\right)$$ (Note that one of your solution is incorrect.)

Answer (score 5):

Square it and see.  It works fine.  In the complex field, you can take the square root of any number.  If we use the polar representation $z=re^{i\theta}$ ($r, \theta$ real), the square roots will be $\sqrt r e^{\frac {i \theta}{2}}$ and $\sqrt r e^{\frac {i \theta}{2}+i\pi}$ 
This extends to $n^{\text {th}}$ roots.  The $n^{\text {th}}$ root of $z=re^{i\theta}$ is $r^{\frac 1n}e^{i(\frac \theta n+\frac {2k\pi}n)}$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots n-1$

Comment: I know it works fine; I just don't think it's right that expressing it requires the very number of which we wish to take the square root.

Comment: @LeeSleek:  First we define the complex numbers, by saying there is something called $i$ such that $i^2=-1$ and they are all the things of the form $a+bi$, with $a,b$ real.  Then we prove they form a field.  Now it is a fair question whether there is something in this set that can be squared to get $i$ and we answer it affirmatively. It is not circular.  We are working in an environment where $i$ is defined already.

Comment: @LeeSleek, note that $\sqrt{1}=\pm 1$; expressing this requires the very number whose square root we are taking.

Comment: @LeeSleek:  Sorry, but this sounds like an attempt to rescue the question.  We define the naturals as successors of $0$ and add addition and multiplication.  Then we say $2^2=4$, which uses something defined before $4$.